# Nutiteq getting coordinates of a location on map

Tags: geolocation, location, coordinates, nutiteq

I am trying to get the Co-ordinates of a location but i can find any way in nutiteq sdk please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following class and you will be able to get the latitude and longitude.

class CustomMarker extends Marker{

```
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;


    public CustomMarker(MapPos markerLocation, Label markerLabel,
            MarkerStyle style, Object object) {
        super(markerLocation, markerLabel,
                style,object);
    }


    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }


    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }


    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }


    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MapPos` returns the coordinates of a Location, [here](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/index.html?com/nutiteq/components//class-useMapPos.html) you can see how to use

I advice, you should read the examples, which contain the SDK, there you can find the more typical operations under `Nutiteq`

Comment: I all ready worked with the examples but still can not find the proper solution.